# looking like Vs that look like

Tags: grammar, gerunds

> She lived in a house looking like a castle

> She lived in a house that looked like a castle

Do they both mean the same? Is it okay to use -ing form in such cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst the intent of both sentences is the same, the first is ambiguous. Whilst few would read it as such, it could mean that she lived in an ordinary house and **she** looked like a castle. Ridiculous I agree, but a possible interpretation.
On the other hand the second sentence has no such problem. The inclusion of **that** ties the description to the house.